# prestashop 1.6 delete item from cart webservice

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to delete item from cart in prestashop 1.6 by adopting code that is working in prestashop 1.4

I'm able to create a product, and add the product to cart using webservice.

Then I try to delete it by removing the product from the cart_rows, here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<cart>
    <id>21</id>
    <id_address_delivery>0</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice>0</id_address_invoice>
    <id_currency>1</id_currency>
    <id_customer>0</id_customer>
    <id_guest>0</id_guest>
    <id_lang>1</id_lang>
    <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
    <id_shop>1</id_shop>
    <id_carrier>0</id_carrier>
    <recyclable>0</recyclable>
    <gift>0</gift>
    <gift_message/>
    <mobile_theme>0</mobile_theme>
    <delivery_option/>
    <secure_key/>
    <allow_seperated_package>0</allow_seperated_package>
<associations>
<cart_rows>
    <cart_row>
    </cart_row>
</cart_rows>
</associations>
</cart>
</prestashop>
```

this return the following exception

> 'PrestaShopWebserviceException' with message 'This call to PrestaShop
>   Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 500. That means:
>   Internal Server Error.'

but the product is actually deleted from the cart!

So I can ignore this exception and move on, but I would like to know how to remove a product from cart with WS without getting an exception

Answer (score 0):

I feel uncomfortable publishing this hack but it's the best I found

The solution uses to webservice request

1. set the quantity to 0:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <cart>
       <id>21</id>
       <id_address_delivery>0</id_address_delivery>
       <id_address_invoice>0</id_address_invoice>
       <id_currency xlink:href="http://localhost:8889/api/currencies/1">1</id_currency>
       <id_customer>0</id_customer>
       <id_guest>0</id_guest>
       <id_lang xlink:href="http://localhost:8889/api/languages/1">1</id_lang>
       <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
       <id_shop>1</id_shop>
       <id_carrier>0</id_carrier>
       <recyclable>0</recyclable>
       <gift>0</gift>
       <gift_message/>
       <mobile_theme>0</mobile_theme>
       <delivery_option/>
       <secure_key/>
       <allow_seperated_package>0</allow_seperated_package>
       <date_add>2016-02-19 23:35:58</date_add>
       <date_upd>2016-02-19 23:35:58</date_upd> <associations> <cart_rows nodeType="cart_row" virtualEntity="true"> <cart_row> 
   <id_product>3</id_product><id_product_attribute>1</id_product_attribute>
   <quantity>0</quantity> 
   </cart_row> </cart_rows> </associations> </cart> </prestashop>
   ```
2. remove the product from the request

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <cart>
       <id>21</id>
       <id_address_delivery>0</id_address_delivery>
       <id_address_invoice>0</id_address_invoice>
       <id_currency xlink:href="http://localhost:8889/api/currencies/1">1</id_currency>
       <id_customer>0</id_customer>
       <id_guest>0</id_guest>
       <id_lang xlink:href="http://localhost:8889/api/languages/1">1</id_lang>
       <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
       <id_shop>1</id_shop>
       <id_carrier>0</id_carrier>
       <recyclable>0</recyclable>
       <gift>0</gift>
       <gift_message/>
       <mobile_theme>0</mobile_theme>
       <delivery_option/>
       <secure_key/>
       <allow_seperated_package>0</allow_seperated_package>
       <date_add>2016-02-19 23:35:58</date_add>
       <date_upd>2016-02-19 23:35:58</date_upd> <associations> <cart_rows nodeType="cart_row" virtualEntity="true"> <cart_row> 
   </cart_row> </cart_rows> </associations> </cart> </prestashop>
   ```